# Gotham Steel Pans

Tags: equipment, induction

I purchased two Gotham Steel 9 and 1/2” pans. I use an induction cook top. This was a match made in hell. Didn’t realize that I needed an interface between the cooktop and pan. What would be the best direction to take?

Comment: Are you certain you got steel pans, I see they also sell titanium pans? do magnets work on your pans ?

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to return the pans for ones made with iron that will work with your cooktop.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use a pan that does not have magnetic steel on an induction cooktop, but it requires as you note an interface - meaning, a piece of magnetic metal that will heat up and transfer heat to the pan.  This won't be nearly as efficient as a pan that is magnetic; so this is not recommended when possible to avoid.  I'd try to return it for a new pan that does work.

When buying a pan, first look for the induction compatible symbol, such as this one: [image: Induction compatible icon, looks like five coils]

That symbol means the manufacturer claims it is compatible; it's not a guarantee, of course, nobody is checking them, but it's a first start - and gives you more solid footing to do the return if it doesn't work.

Second, if you're shopping in person, bring a magnet with you.  Note how well the magnet sticks to the pan.  If it sticks immediately, then it's great; if it weakly sticks, then it might work - but may not be as efficient (I had a pan when I bought my cooktop that did have weak magnetism, but only worked about half the time - the sensor that determined the pan size didn't see the pan half the time; had to give that one away).

Third, make sure you're looking at the right kind of pan.  Induction won't work well with a pan with a narrow base - like many woks - as the size of contact surface determines how well it heats.  There are woks that can work with an induction stove, but it's very different from how they work on a gas stove.  Wider bottom base is better for induction.

Finally, when you get the pan, see how quickly it heats up.  Compare it to a pan you know works well.  That will tell you if it's performing well - it should boil water quickly, for example.